# What is the limit of the topic string in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

Does RabbitMQ have a limit in the topic size?

I've looked around the web but was not able to find any reasonable answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum length of a topic exchange's routing key is 255 bytes.

From [the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html) (see the "Topic exchange" subsection):

> *There can be as many words in the routing key as you like, up to the limit of 255 bytes.*

---

**Update**

This length is defined as part of the AMQP version 0.9.1 specification.

You can see the related documentation here: [basic.publish.routing-key](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.publish.routing-key):

> `shortstr` routing-key
>
> Specifies the routing key for the message. The routing key is used for routing messages depending on the exchange configuration.

The data type of the routing key is `shortstr` which has a [separate definition](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#domain.shortstr):

> `shortstr` - short string (max. 256 characters)

Note that here the documentation actually say "*256 characters*" - which is different from the tutorial documentation of "*255 bytes*".

(I have not created a routing key using multibyte characters. So "bytes" may or may not equal "characters", here.)